# JSON Response and Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from the New York Times API with Scrapy to CSV so that I could have a summary of all related articles to a particular query. I'd like to spit this out as a CSV with link, publication date, summary, and title so that I could run a few keyword searches on the summary description. I'm new to both Python and Scrapy but here's my spider (I'm getting an HTTP 400 error). I've xx'ed out my api key in the spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from nytimesAPIjson.items import NytimesapijsonItem
import json
import urllib2

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "nytimesapijson"
    allowed_domains = ["http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch"]
    req = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q="financial crime"&facet_field=day_of_week&begin_date=20130101&end_date=20130916&page=2&rank=newest&api-key=xxx)

      def json_parse(self, response):
          jsonresponse= json.loads(response)

          item = NytimesapijsonItem()
          item ["pubDate"] = jsonresponse["pub_date"]
          item ["description"] = jsonresponse["lead_paragraph"]
          item ["title"] = jsonresponse["print_headline"]
          item ["link"] = jsonresponse["web_url"]
          items.append(item)
          return items
```

If anybody has any ideas/suggestions, including onese outside of Scrapy, please let me know.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 400 means that the GET request in the url is malformed.  Maybe try sort=newest, instead of rank=newest.

http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2

Comment: still having the same issue but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've actually been able to fix the HTTP error, but now the CSV file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `start_urls` and use `parse` method:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
import json


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "nytimesapijson"
    allowed_domains = ["api.nytimes.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q="financial crime"&facet_field=day_of_week&begin_date=20130101&end_date=20130916&page=2&rank=newest&api-key=xxx']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response)

        print jsonresponse
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that works to print to the screen. Now is there any way to map that to the items and convert to CSV.

Comment: @eroma934 yeah, you have it in the code actually. I'd just omitted it for the example.

Comment: The only problem is that I am getting a GET error when I keep the item syntax in. It's because I'm missing a loop (I think), but I'm not sure what the json equivalent for hxs.select would be in the typical spider. I really appreciate your input.